# Using 2 gridviews with different models of same class Yii2 independently

Tags: php, gridview, yii2

I have a view that shows 2 gridviews of the same model class, however, they seem to use the same filter, sort and pagination, even though they use different search models and dataProviders like so:

In the controller:

```
public function actionIndex()
{
    $searchModel = new CasoAccionSearch();
    $dataProvider = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);
    $dataProvider->pagination->pageParam = "tarea-propia-page";
    $dataProvider->sort->sortParam = "tarea-propia-sort";

    $searchModelTerceros = new CasoAccionSearch();
    $dataProviderTerceros = $searchModelTerceros->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);
    $dataProviderTerceros->pagination->pageParam = "tarea-3ros-page";
    $dataProviderTerceros->sort->sortParam = "tarea-3ros-sort";

    return $this->render('myIndex', [
        'searchModel' => $searchModel,
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        'searchModelTerceros' => $searchModelTerceros,
        'dataProviderTerceros' => $dataProviderTerceros,
    ]);
}
```

And in the view:

```
<?= GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'filterModel' => $searchModel,
    'columns' => [
       // ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],

        'acc_referencia',
        'acc_fecha_accion',
        'fecha_creacion',
        [
            'label' => 'Creado Por',
            'format' => 'raw',
            'value' => function($data){
                return $data->abCreador->nombreCompleto;
            }
        ],
        //'ab_creacion',
        [
            'label' => 'Caso',
            'format' => 'raw',
            'value' => function($data){
                return Html::a($data->caso->caso_nombre,
                        Yii::$app->urlManager->createUrl(['caso/view','id'=>$data->caso_id]));
            }
        ],
        // 'caso.caso_nombre',
        'acc_descripcion:ntext',
        'caso.caso_referencia',
        [
            'label' => 'Cliente',
            'format' => 'raw',
            'value' => function($data){
                return Html::a($data->caso->cliente->nombreCliente,
                        Yii::$app->urlManager->createUrl(['cliente/view','id'=>$data->caso->cl_id]));
            }
        ],  
        // 'resp_id',
        // 'acc_tipo',
        // 'estado',
        // 'acc_horas_estimadas',
        // 'acc_horas_ejecutadas',
        // 'acc_fecha_accion',
        // 'acc_descripcion:ntext',
        // 'fecha_creacion',
        // 'ab_creacion',

        ['class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn'],
    ],
]); ?>


<?= GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProviderTerceros,
    'filterModel' => $searchModelTerceros,
    'columns' => [
        ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],
        'acc_referencia',
        'acc_fecha_accion',
        'fecha_creacion',
        'caso.caso_nombre',
        [
            'label' => 'Responsable',
            'format' => 'raw',
            'value' => function($data){
                return $data->abResponsable->nombreCompleto;
            }
        ],
        //'abResponsable.ab_nombres',
        'acc_descripcion:ntext',
        'caso.caso_referencia',
        [
            'label' => 'Cliente',
            'format' => 'raw',
            'value' => function($data){
                return Html::a($data->caso->cliente->nombreCliente,
                        Yii::$app->urlManager->createUrl(['cliente/view','id'=>$data->caso->cl_id]));
            }
        ],
        ['class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn'],
    ],
]); ?>
```

Any ideas about how to make them behave independently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see you have already configured different pagination and sorting parameters for both models. That is correct, so all you need to fix is filtering.

Your filtering applies to both grids, because your form element names are the same. Your search model has the [`formName()`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-base-model.html#formName%28%29-detail) method, which returns a string. By default, it returns class name. So, when you try to filter on `acc_referencia` in any of the forms, the following parameter is added to your url: `CasoAccionSearch[acc_referencia]`. It is then picked up by both grids which is not your desired behavior. What you should make instead is `grid1[acc_referencia]` for first grid and `grid2[acc_referencia]` for second grid.

You have two choices here: either implement `CasoAccionSearch::formName()` in such a way that it returns two different form names for two different instances of `CasoAccionSearch`, or just use two different search models.

I suggest you do it this way:

```
class CasoAccionSearch
{
    public $formNameParam = 'CasoAccionSearch';
    // ...
    // other attributes

    public function formName()
    {
        return $this->formNameParam;
    }
    // ...
    // other methods
}
```

And then in your view:

```
$searchModel = new CasoAccionSearch(['formNameParam' => 'grid1']);
$dataProvider = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);
```

For consistency, I would also make `pageParam` and `sortParam` attributes of `CasoAccionSearch` that get passed to the data provider in `search()`.

Comment: Thank you! that was exactly what i needed

Answer (score 0):

They use the same class  CasoAccionSearch() and then the same  search function .. if you need two separated function you need a proper search function  eg:

```
class CasoAccionSearch extends CasoAccion
{
    .....
   public function search($params)
   {
      .......
   }


    public function search2($params)   // searc for second grid 
    {
        .......
    }
```

and the adapt you controller/action code for use the two different search function ..